# How to open a servlet page webapps\classes\HelloWorld?

Tags: java, html, servlets, tomcat7, web.xml

I have placed my HTML page in `webapps\root\WebForte` folder of my Tomcat. I want to open a servlet page `webapps\classes\HelloWorld`.

I have already mentioned the following in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HeloWorld</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/classes/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

and called the class from the following

```
<form  id="docContainer" action = "HelloWorld" method="POST">
```

I am getting `HTTP Status 404 - /WebForte/HelloWorld` error. Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Do a google search on the meaning of `url-pattern`.

Comment: shouldnt you place your application under webapps\WebForte  ?

Comment: Or, read our servlets tag wiki page for an extensive Hello World example. Hover the `[servlets]` tag which you placed on the question until a black info box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Comment: Hello  Frederic, I tried the same but still the error is same. even though i have mapped the page on web.xml. I want to keep all the classes in the same page so that it can be on different position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the root directory,just place your webapp under "webapps"

According to your web.xml to  access yor servlet  you need this url:

/classes/HelloWorld

In other words whenever tomcat sees "/classes/HelloWorld" it maps it to your servlet and sends the request there.

My guess is that according the 404 error your url should be  /WebForte/classes/HelloWorld

Also keep in mind that "/classes/HelloWorld" is somthing arbitrary, you put wahtever you like there

To figure out what's going on try the url from a browser

[The directory structure should look like this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Standard_Directory_Layout):

```
webapps     
| 
- WebForte
  |
  - WEB-INF
    |
     -web.xml
     -classes
       |
         -HelloWorld.class
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I tried what you have mentioned in your reply but the wrror message not shows just "HTTP Status 404 -". I hope something is not wrong with my tomcat7 version or maybe the code I have written in my servlet page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try http://localhost:8008 in yr browser does it work?

Comment: Yes it works, Even my index page works at http://localhost:8080/WebForte/ works properly. but on submit button it shows 404 error

Comment: try http://localhost:8080/WebForte/classes/HelloWorld in yr browser, does it work?

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class HeloWorld is the error that comes up when i put http://localhost:8080/WebForte/classes/HelloWorld in url

Comment: Is your directory structure like the one above in the answer?

Comment: Yes i have used the same path now. but still the same issue.

Comment: That's not correct. It should be C:\tomcat-7\webapps\WebForte\WEB-INF\classes\HelloWorld.class

Comment: Yes, I have just tried this path also. but this HelloWorld doesnt seem to work at all

Answer (score 0):

you need put the parameter `<display-name>` in your definition exactly like this:

```
 <servlet>
        <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.yourpackage.servlet.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and your servlet would be visible to request.

Comment: Hi Christian, Thanks a lot for your reply, I tried it with Display name also but it didnt work.